"Full authentication is required to access this resource" even with passed a valid JWT token
so far I've mostly worked with C# and ASP.NET, but now have to write a Web API in Java Spring. I'm totally new in this environment and cannot deal with JWT token authentication, this looks like black magic to me. If I open an endpoint for anonymous user they work fine, but when I try to require authentiation, I'm always getting 401 Unauthorized status code, even if I pass a valid JWT token in my request. This is my security config class:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final JwtAuthEntryPoint authEntryPoint;
    private final UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfig(JwtAuthEntryPoint authEntryPoint, UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService) {
        this.authEntryPoint = authEntryPoint;
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .exceptionHandling(e -> {
                    e.authenticationEntryPoint(authEntryPoint);
                })
                .authorizeHttpRequests(r -> {
                   
                    r.requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/authentication/respondents").authenticated();
                })
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration)
            throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public Filter jwtAuthenticationFilter() {
        return new JwtAuthenticationFilter();
    }
}

My token provider
@Component
public class TokenProvider {

    private final SecuritySettings securitySettings;

    @Autowired
    public TokenProvider(SecuritySettings securitySettings) {
        this.securitySettings = securitySettings;
    }

    public String generateToken(Authentication authentication){
        String username = authentication.getName();
        Date curretDate = new Date();
        int expiration = securitySettings.getExpiration();
        Date expireDate = new Date(curretDate.getTime() + expiration);

        String token = Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject(username)
                .setIssuedAt(curretDate)
                .setExpiration(expireDate)
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, securitySettings.getKey())
                .compact();


        return token;
    }

    public String getUsernameFromJwt(String token){
        Claims claims = Jwts.parser()
                .setSigningKey(securitySettings.getKey())
                .parseClaimsJws(token)
                .getBody();

        return claims.getSubject();
    }

    public boolean validateToken(String token){
        try{
            Jwts.parser()
                    .setSigningKey(securitySettings.getKey())
                    .parseClaimsJws(token);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e){
            throw new AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException("Jwt was expired or incorrect");
        }
    }
}

Authentication filter:
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private TokenProvider tokenProvider;
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;


    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                    HttpServletResponse response,
                                    FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String token = getJWTFromRequest(request);
        if (StringUtils.hasText(token) && tokenProvider.validateToken(token)){
            String username = tokenProvider.getUsernameFromJwt(token);

            UserDetails user = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user,
                    user.getAuthorities());
            authenticationToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private String getJWTFromRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String bearerToken = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (StringUtils.hasText(bearerToken) && bearerToken.startsWith("Bearer ")){
            return bearerToken.substring(7, bearerToken.length());
        }

        return null;
    }
}

user details service implementation:
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    private IdentityUserRepository identityUserRepository;

    @Autowired
    public UserDetailsServiceImpl(IdentityUserRepository identityUserRepository) {
        this.identityUserRepository = identityUserRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
            IdentityUser databaseUser = identityUserRepository
                    .findByUsername(username)
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("Username not found"));
            return new User(databaseUser.getUsername(), databaseUser.getPasswordHash(), mapRolesToAuthorities(databaseUser));
    }

    private List<GrantedAuthority> mapRolesToAuthorities(IdentityUser user){
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + user.getRole()));
        return authorities;
    }

}

I've spent about 15 hours trying to find some information and resolve this, but nothing helps. The only thing I have discovered is that I always get to this entry point:
@Component
public class JwtAuthEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {
    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, authException.getMessage());
    }
}

And I think 401 is returned from here. The exception message says "Full authentication is required to access this resource"... I'd be so grateful If someone helped me. Maybe I'll also mention, that my target is to limit the endpoint to admin users with hasRole("ADMIN") (this also leaves me with 401). And to be clear - the JWT Bearer token passed in the Authentication header is valid.
Logs (maybe helpful):
[2024-07-05 21:46:18.240] [ERROR] [http-nio-auto-1-exec-1] c.s.api.handlers.GlobalExceptionHandler - Full authentication is required to access this resource org.springframework.security.authentication.InsufficientAuthenticationException: Full authentication is required to access this resource
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.handleAccessDeniedException(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.handleSpringSecurityException(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:178)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:147)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$AroundFilterObservation$SimpleAroundFilterObservation.lambda$wrap$0(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:224)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector.lambda$createCacheFilter$3(HandlerMappingIntrospector.java:195)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebMvcSecurityConfiguration$CompositeFilterChainProxy.doFilter(WebMvcSecurityConfiguration.java:230)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:642)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:410)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:340)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:277)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:362)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:151)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842)



For us to help, you should provide some logs for spring-security, DEBUG logs would be the best.
If you do, check the logs for any kind of "token expired" or similiar.
Why dont you use the standard BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter? Try to stick to spring-security's default. Configure jwt() for a start for HttpSecurity. It registers filters, authenticationproviders.
Also note that you configured basic authentication as backup after your custom Jwt jwtAuthenticationFilter.


Thank you for your response. I updated the question with a log. I can't see any helpful information there, but maybe there are not helpful just because I'm not a Java dev

@pawelfelcyn Please include the DEBUG logs for a full (failed-) authentication. The stacktrace alone is not helping much.
